# Rjs calander skip month change

Tags: asp.net

Rjs calander skip month change when I am using mouse pad and change the month it's skip month ex(I am click on March month to previous month that means Feb but it's skip Feb show January)but no issue in mouse only using laptop how to solve this issue using asp.net